# R two same size corrplots side by side

Tags: r, plot, correlation

Let's assume two (or more) dataframes

```
v1 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
df1 <- data.frame("Very_long_variable_name_1" = v1, 
                  "Very_long_variable_name_2" = v1 + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1))
df2 <- data.frame("Very_long_variable_name_1" = 3*v1 - 1, 
                  "Very_long_variable_name_2" = 2*v1 + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1))
```

Now I can create correlation matrices

```
cors1 <- cor(df1, method = "pearson")
cors2 <- cor(df2, method = "pearson")
```

The problem is that the rownames and colnames of these correlation matrices are very long and thus difficult to sensibly plot. I can mitigate that by mapping them into something else, i.e.

```
fun <- function(corr, shortName)
{
  if(shortName)
  {
    rownames(corr) <- c("V1", "V2")
  }
  colnames(corr) <- c("V1", "V2")
  return(corr)
}
cp1 <- corrplot::corrplot(fun(cors1, FALSE),  method = "color")
cp2 <- corrplot::corrplot(fun(cors2, TRUE),  method = "color")
```

However, when I plot them side by side, the first corrplot is smaller due to the fact that the full rownames are also shown

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
cp1 <- corrplot::corrplot(fun(cors1, FALSE),  method = "color")
cp2 <- corrplot::corrplot(fun(cors2, TRUE),  method = "color")
```

[image]

Is there any way to make them of the same size? Or to add some kind of legend (e.g. "V1: Very_long_variable_name1") outside of the plot area?

**EDIT**: one solution that I found is to simply use `layout()` function:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2), 
              nrow = 1, 
              ncol = 2, 
              byrow = TRUE),
       widths =  c(1.5,1))
cp1 <- corrplot::corrplot(fun(cors1, FALSE), method = "color")
cp2 <- corrplot::corrplot(fun(cors2, TRUE), method = "color")
```

However, it requires a manual choice of widths for each plot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to combine the base-graphics plots, but if your data is similarly structured as your example, then you can use `ggplot2` and `patchwork`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

fillrange <- range(c(cors1, cors2))
gg1 <- ggplot(as.data.frame.table(fun(cors1, FALSE)), aes(Var2, Var1, fill = Freq)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_continuous(limits = fillrange)
gg2 <- ggplot(as.data.frame.table(fun(cors2, TRUE)), aes(Var2, Var1, fill = Freq)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_continuous(limits = fillrange)
gg1 + gg2 +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect", axes = "collect")
```

[image]

As a bonus, the colorbar legend is combined, so the colors between plots is comparable. (This step was optional, you can remove the `guides="collect"` and the two calls to `scale_fill_continuous(limits=)` if that is not desired.)